# when i am trying to execute pip3 install tf-models-official command on window 11 with CPU and using conda for creating virtual environment

Tags: python, tensorflow, github, model, tensorflow2.0

Getting below error have installed python 3.11.0 and tensor flow 2.13.0

Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [68 lines of output]
C:\Users\vibho\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nzr3tj5m\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\config\setupcfg.py:293: _DeprecatedConfig: Deprecated config in `setup.cfg`
!!

```
          ********************************************************************************
          The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.

          By 2023-Oct-30, you need to update your project and remove deprecated calls
          or your builds will no longer be supported.

          See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html for details.
          ********************************************************************************

  !!
    parsed = self.parsers.get(option_name, lambda x: x)(value)
  running egg_info
  writing lib3\PyYAML.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to lib3\PyYAML.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to lib3\PyYAML.egg-info\top_level.txt
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\vibho\.conda\envs\balaji\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Users\vibho\.conda\envs\balaji\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\vibho\.conda\envs\balaji\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\vibho\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nzr3tj5m\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 355, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\vibho\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nzr3tj5m\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in _get_build_requires
      self.run_setup()
    File "C:\Users\vibho\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nzr3tj5m\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
      exec(code, locals())
    File "<string>", line 271, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\vibho\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nzr3tj5m\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 107, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\vibho\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nzr3tj5m\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
      return run_commands(dist)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\vibho\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nzr3tj5m\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\Users\vibho\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nzr3tj5m\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\Users\vibho\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nzr3tj5m\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1233, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\vibho\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nzr3tj5m\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\vibho\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nzr3tj5m\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 319, in run
      self.find_sources()
    File "C:\Users\vibho\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nzr3tj5m\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 327, in find_sources
      mm.run()
    File "C:\Users\vibho\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nzr3tj5m\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 549, in run
      self.add_defaults()
    File "C:\Users\vibho\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nzr3tj5m\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 587, in add_defaults
      sdist.add_defaults(self)
    File "C:\Users\vibho\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nzr3tj5m\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\sdist.py", line 113, in add_defaults
      super().add_defaults()
    File "C:\Users\vibho\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nzr3tj5m\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\sdist.py", line 251, in add_defaults
      self._add_defaults_ext()
    File "C:\Users\vibho\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nzr3tj5m\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\sdist.py", line 336, in _add_defaults_ext
      self.filelist.extend(build_ext.get_source_files())
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "<string>", line 201, in get_source_files
    File "C:\Users\vibho\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nzr3tj5m\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 107, in __getattr__
      raise AttributeError(attr)
  AttributeError: cython_sources
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.